# YOCTO (MORTY) activate bash completion

Tags: bash, yocto, bitbake

I tried to add bash completion with

IMAGE_FEATURE += "bash-completion"

but the /etc/bash_completion.d is empty in the image.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "bash-completion"` or `IMAGE_INSTALL += "bash-completion"` in you image recipe or in your `local.conf`